# ASP.NET uploading image with just button click

Tags: asp.net, image, file-upload

Is there any controls that I can download that allows a user to upload images with just a button click and be able to open the file dialog. I  do not want to use the fileupload control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for something with better asthetics, Steve Sanderson has a nice Ajax uploader with a progress bar you can check out. Pretty straightforward installation.

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/11/24/jquery-ajax-uploader-plugin-with-progress-bar/

Comment: this works very nicely thank you. Would you know how I can strip out the full path and just show the filename within the text ara?

Comment: Are you talking about after its uploaded? I'm trying to remember off the top of my head but I believe the controller action should return the filename as a string.

Answer (score 1):

According to me: no. It would open a security hole as if you don't let an enduser decide which file to select from his/her drive an application would be able to leech anything from that drive.

The ASP.NET fileupload control itself simply renders to an `<input type="file">` html element. How the browser renders that is up to the browser. However it can be styled. For example like this: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html.

If it's on a corporate LAN and there's a certain file on a users drive and (s)he opens your page then you might want to use something like a custom written ActiveX control which can be embedded in the rendered html to perform the task.
A variant on this one would be to create a winforms user control, embed that into the rendered html (a so called smart client), with enough CAS settings on the client pc to be able to do this.

Comment: well is there a  nicer looking versionat least because that conrol is absolutely hideous

Comment: Errr, which control are you talking about? I didn't point out to one specifically.

Comment: I was talking about the fileupload control available is asp, sorry I realized I wadnt descriptive witin my original question. I still want to open the file dialog  though,just don't want to use that ugly fileupload control

Comment: I added some extra information about how to style the <input type="file"> html element.